# Firebase Fire store database How to Display the added data in Text Box?

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone give me example on displaying the added data in the text box? I'm new on using Firebase Fire store database. I'm creating an app where the user will input name, address, nickname, gender. Then, after inserted the data would be displayed in a text box.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple example, use the Firestore `get()` to [retrieve data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#kotlin+ktx) and [display it to the user](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView) in Android `TextView`. For example:

Suppose you have a database, like in the Firestore documentation, named `cities` with a document `SF`. In your app's interface you have a `TextView` with ID `user_input` and you want to display its contents to the user.

```
val user_input = findViewById(R.id.user_input) as TextView // find the required element in the app's interface 

val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
    docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}") //logs the content to the console before displaying
                    user_input.text = document.getString(field:user_input) //displays data to the user
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
            }
```